# Catching HTTP errors before redirect via 51degrees (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, http-error, 51degrees

I am using 51degrees.mobi and it is working well but in the case of the mobile server experiencing issues (HTTP error status) I want to be able to allow the user to continue on with the desktop version of the mobile site.  I know I can stop the redirect by commenting out the redirect section of the config but is it possible to stop the redirect pragmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently working for 51Degrees.mobi.

If I understand you correctly then what you are asking to do is not possible through 51Degrees as you cannot change the configuration rules.

However what you want to do may be possible by editing your web.config file so that it will send you to the normal page if an error code is thrown using a customErrors element? More information on doing that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It may also be possible to do by modifying your pages [PreInit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx#Y0) event.

Hope this helps.